# Inno Setup - How to edit the "About Setup" dialog text box

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to edit or replace the text in the `About Setup` dialog box text of Inno Setup.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Looking in the internet i got this code:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: CallbackCtrl.dll; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
type
  TWFProc = function(h:hWnd;Msg,wParam,lParam:Longint):Longint;

function CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndFunc: Longint; hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: Longint; lParam: Longint): Longint; external 'CallWindowProcA@user32.dll stdcall';
function SetWindowLong(Wnd: HWnd; Index: Integer; NewLong: Longint): Longint; external 'SetWindowLongA@user32.dll stdcall';
function WrapWFProc(Callback: TWFProc; ParamCount: Integer): Longword; external 'wrapcallbackaddr@files:CallbackCtrl.dll stdcall';

var
  OldProc:Longint;

procedure AboutSetupClick;
begin
  //Edit your text here
  MsgBox('CUSTOM TEXT HERE', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

function WFWndProc(h:HWND;Msg,wParam,lParam:Longint):Longint;
begin
  if (Msg=$112) and (wParam=9999) then begin
    Result:=0;
    AboutSetupClick;
  end else begin
    if Msg=$2 then SetWindowLong(WizardForm.Handle,-4,OldProc);
    Result:=CallWindowProc(OldProc,h,Msg,wParam,lParam);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  OldProc:=SetWindowLong(WizardForm.Handle,-4,WrapWFProc(@WFWndProc,4));
end;
```

Seems to work fine..

[image]

But if i close the installer, i get crash message.

[image]

Please i need help to fix this code or give a better example to change the text in the About Setup dialog text box.

The DLL i used.
[HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/?ahsufiayt7fp8p2)

Comment: Well, if I overlook what you're going to do (you know this won't be legal, right ?) and which library are you using (some sort of suspicious *"I found it on the Internet and don't care it might contain a virus"* library), you need to give the original window procedure back to the wizard form. Try to restore it in the `DeinitializeSetup` event. And, -4, $2 and $112 are not the well named constants ;-)

Comment: :( I Asked before in this forum... i will not use, put or give any virus, that dll is from the dll pack of inno setup (ultra), i didnt know this was a problem, i just want to customize my installer... and i need some help :(

Comment: I see that it's not your intention, but be very careful with this. If I were virus developer, installer extensions would be a great place to play just because they're running usually elevated (what might allow the virus do whatever you need). I don't want to test that library, I just know that you need to give the original window procedure (the `OldProc` in your example) back to the wizard form before you quit. So maybe something like `SetWindowLong(WizardForm.Handle, -4, OldProc);` called from the `DeinitializeSetup` event should help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: @TLama, My thoughts exactly. What I'm doing in my setup programs, is I leave the original "about" text (for legal/moral reasons) and utilize `TranslatorNote` key (in the `isl` file) to add my own stuff. Replacing `GWL_WNDPROC` for *this* seems kinda extreme and even out of proportions...

Comment: Note that it is one of the license requirements of Inno to leave all of the existing text in here intact.  If you're only adding text that's ok, but you're not permitted to change anything existing.  And as kobik notes there is a simpler way to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give the saved original windows procedure back to the wizard form before you exit the setup application. To do so, use something like this:

```pascal
const
  GWL_WNDPROC = -4;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  SetWindowLong(WizardForm.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, OldProc);
end;
```

Anyway, you can use more trustful library for wrapping callbacks, the [`InnoCallback`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=55) library. I've made a review of the code you used and added support for Unicode InnoSetup versions, expecting the use of the `InnoCallback` library:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "InnoCallback.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
const
  GWL_WNDPROC = -4;
  SC_ABOUTBOX = 9999;
  WM_SYSCOMMAND = $0112;

type
  WPARAM = UINT_PTR;
  LPARAM = LongInt;
  LRESULT = LongInt;
  TWindowProc = function(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; 
    lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;

function CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndFunc: LongInt; hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; 
  wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
  external 'CallWindowProc{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';  
function SetWindowLong(hWnd: HWND; nIndex: Integer; 
  dwNewLong: LongInt): LongInt;
  external 'SetWindowLong{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';    
function WrapWindowProc(Callback: TWindowProc; ParamCount: Integer): LongWord;
  external 'wrapcallback@files:InnoCallback.dll stdcall'; 

var
  OldWndProc: LongInt;

procedure ShowAboutBox;
begin
  MsgBox('Hello, I''m your about box!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

function WndProc(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; 
  lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
begin
  if (uMsg = WM_SYSCOMMAND) and (wParam = SC_ABOUTBOX) then
  begin
    Result := 0;
    ShowAboutBox;
  end
  else
    Result := CallWindowProc(OldWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  OldWndProc := SetWindowLong(WizardForm.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, 
    WrapWindowProc(@WndProc, 4));
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  SetWindowLong(WizardForm.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, OldWndProc);
end;
```

Comment: With Inno Setup 6, you can use [`CreateCallback(@WndProc)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback) and you do not need the  InnoCallback at all (so these can be removed: `Source: "InnoCallback.dll"` and `function WrapWindowProc`).

Answer (score 0):

Future visitors see this similar post:
[Inno Setup - How can I change the About dialog text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61737682/inno-setup-how-can-i-change-the-about-dialog-text)

Try to use the built-in function for this:

- Override the `AboutSetupNote` or  `TranslatorNote` message... neither of this will change the about box message but they will append to it which is the correct application of Inno Setup license.