# Inno Setup Disable close button (X)

Tags: inno-setup

How to disable the Close button (borderstyle)?

I want to combine that with hiding *"About Setup"* command from system menu:
[Inno Setup - BorderIcons dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109238/850848)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`EnableMenuItem` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablemenuitem):

```pascal
function GetSystemMenu(hWnd: THandle; bRevert: Boolean): THandle;
  external 'GetSystemMenu@user32.dll stdcall';

function EnableMenuItem(hMenu: UINT; uIDEnableItem, uEnable: UINT): Boolean;
  external 'EnableMenuItem@user32.dll stdcall';

const
  MF_GRAYED = $1;
  MF_BYCOMMAND = $0;
  SC_CLOSE = $F060;

procedure DisableCloseButton;
var
  Menu: THandle;
begin
  Menu := GetSystemMenu(WizardForm.Handle, False);
  EnableMenuItem(Menu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND or MF_GRAYED);
end;
```

You have to call the `DisableCloseButton` **later** than from the `InitializeWizard` event function.

There maybe a better place to call it, but for a simplicity you can call it from `CurPageChanged`:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  DisableCloseButton;
end;
```

But note that you need to keep [the code to hide *"About Setup"* command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109238/850848) in `InitializeWizard` as that needs to be called only once (and it works there correctly).

The screenshot shows both codes combined:

[image]