# Inno Setup - How can I change the About dialog text?

Tags: inno-setup

Can I change the default text in the about dialog box?  Overriding the `AboutSetupMessage` doesn't seem to do anything:

```
[Messages]
AboutSetupMenuItem=&About MyApp...
AboutSetupTitle=About MyApp
AboutSetupMessage={#MyAppPublisher} version {#MyAppVersion}%n{#MyCopyright}%nhome page:%n{#MyAppURL}
```

Doesn't seem to matter if I edit the `default.isl` or use a custom ISL either.  The menu item and the title change, but not the message text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `AboutSetupMessage`.

There's `AboutSetupNote`. It does not *change* the About box message though. It's *appended* to it.

There's no way to *change* the message.

Answer (score 0):

For me the `AboutSetupNote` did not work on `Inno Setup 5.6.1 Unicode`, but the `TranslatorNote` did.

Alternatively try `TranslatorNote`. This one does not change the about box message but it will append to it which is the correct application of Inno Setup license.