# Adding context menu to Inno Setup page

Tags: windows, inno-setup

How can I add some context menu to a specific page of Inno Setup?

For example in installing page, if the user right-clicks on-page, he can see "Cancel" or "Pause" menu items which can do some action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inno Setup does not have an API how context menus, not even for handling mouse clicks. So you need to implement a custom Windows message handler and handle `WM_CONTEXTMENU`.

```pascal
[Code]

const
  GWL_WNDPROC = -4;
  WM_CONTEXTMENU = $007B;
  WM_COMMAND = $0111;

type
  WPARAM = UINT_PTR;
  LPARAM = LongInt;
  LRESULT = LongInt;

const
  MF_BYPOSITION = $0400;
  MF_STRING = $0000;

const
  ID_MUTE = 0;
  ID_STOP = 1;

function CallWindowProc(
  lpPrevWndFunc: LongInt; hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM;
  lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; external 'CallWindowProcW@user32.dll stdcall';  
function SetWindowLong(hWnd: HWND; nIndex: Integer; dwNewLong: LongInt): LongInt;
  external 'SetWindowLongW@user32.dll stdcall';    
function CreatePopupMenu: THandle; external 'CreatePopupMenu@User32.dll stdcall';
function InsertMenu(
  hMenu: THandle; uPosition: Cardinal; uFlags: Cardinal; uIDNewItem: Cardinal;
  lpNewItem: string): Boolean;
  external 'InsertMenuW@User32.dll stdcall';
function TrackPopupMenu(
  hMenu: THandle; uFlags: Cardinal; x: Integer; y: Integer; nReserved: Integer;
  hWnd: THandle; Rect: Integer): Boolean; 
  external 'TrackPopupMenu@User32.dll stdcall';
function ClientToScreen(hWnd: HWND; var lpPoint: TPoint): Boolean;
  external 'ClientToScreen@user32.dll stdcall';
  
var
  OldPageWndProc: LongInt;
  Page: TWizardPage;

function GET_X_LPARAM(dw: DWORD): WORD; // aka LOWORD
begin
  Result := WORD(dw);
end;

function GET_Y_LPARAM(dw: DWORD): WORD; // aka HIWORD
begin
  Result := WORD((dw shr 16) and $FFFF);
end;

function PageWndProc(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
var
  PopupMenu: THandle;
  X, Y: Integer;
begin
  if uMsg = WM_CONTEXTMENU then
  begin
    X := GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
    Y := GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam); 

    PopupMenu := CreatePopupMenu();
    InsertMenu(PopupMenu, -1, MF_BYPOSITION or MF_STRING, ID_MUTE, 'Mute');
    InsertMenu(PopupMenu, -1, MF_BYPOSITION or MF_STRING, ID_STOP, 'Stop');
    TrackPopupMenu(PopupMenu, 0, X, Y, 0, Page.Surface.Handle, 0);
  end
    else
  if uMsg = WM_COMMAND then
  begin
    if wParam = ID_MUTE then
    begin
      MsgBox('Muting', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      Result := 0;
    end
      else
    if wParam = ID_STOP then
    begin
      MsgBox('Stopping', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      Result := 0;
    end;
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := CallWindowProc(OldPageWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Page with context menu', '');

  OldPageWndProc :=
    SetWindowLong(Page.Surface.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, CreateCallback(@PageWndProc));
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  SetWindowLong(Page.Surface.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, OldPageWndProc);
end;
```

*The `GWL_WNDPROC` code is based on [Inno Setup - How to edit the "About Setup" dialog text box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14828144/850848)*.

*If you want to add icons, see [Adding an icon image to context menu in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64097924/850848)*.

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*

[image]