# Adding an icon image to context menu in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, winapi, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using the script here to add some context menu to my Inno Setup pages:
[Adding context menu to Inno Setup page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079373/adding-context-menu-to-inno-setup-page/64086762?noredirect=1#comment113345290_64086762)

is there any way to add an icon image to every menu item?

Comment: I think it was mentioned that you use `SetMenuItemBitmaps`. In your linked answer you have examples of how the MFC API methods were transferred to Delphi. The definition for that API here here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuitembitmaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SetMenuItemBitmaps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuitembitmaps):

```pascal
[Code]
const
  IMAGE_BITMAP = 0;
  LR_LOADFROMFILE = $10;
  LR_CREATEDIBSECTION = $2000;

function LoadImage(
  hInst: Integer; ImageName: string; ImageType: UINT; X, Y: Integer;
  Flags: UINT): THandle; external 'LoadImageW@User32.dll stdcall';  
function SetMenuItemBitmaps(
  hMenu: THandle; uPosition: Cardinal; uFlags: Cardinal;
  hBitmapUnchecked: THandle; hBitmapChecked: THandle): Boolean;
  external 'SetMenuItemBitmaps@User32.dll stdcall';

procedure AddMenuItem(
  Menu: THandle; Position: Integer; ID: Integer; Caption: string;
  ImageFileName: string);
var
  Bitmap: THandle;
begin
  InsertMenu(Menu, Position, MF_BYPOSITION or MF_STRING, ID, Caption);
  ExtractTemporaryFile(ImageFileName);
  Bitmap := LoadImage(
    0, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\') + ImageFileName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
    LR_LOADFROMFILE or LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
  SetMenuItemBitmaps(Menu, Position, MF_BYPOSITION, Bitmap, Bitmap);
end;
```

Use the `AddMenuItem` instead of `InsertMenu` calls in the code from [Adding context menu to Inno Setup page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64079373/850848):

```pascal
AddMenuItem(PopupMenu, 0, ID_MUTE, 'Mute', 'mute.bmp');
AddMenuItem(PopupMenu, 1, ID_STOP, 'Stop', 'stop.bmp');
```

The above obviously assumes, that you have the transparent bitmap images added to the installer:

```
[Files]
Source: "mute.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "stop.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy
```

I've used [PixelFormer](https://www.qualibyte.com/pixelformer/) to create the transparent .bmp images.

[image]